# wrap each line with a function and collect each value outputs from an org src block

Tags: org-babel

How do I wrap each line with a function and collect all value outputs from an org src block and collect all value outputs from an org src block?

For example,

If I have

```
#+begin_src python
3492-134.2
3492-134.2+1428
#+end_src
```

I would like

```
#+RESULTS:
: 3357.8
: 4785.8
```

Not

```
#+RESULTS:
: 4785.8
```

According to https://orgmode.org/manual/Results-of-Evaluation.html, adding  `:results output` to the header will collect every output to the standard stream.
But that would require me to add a print statement to each line manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would changing the input to a table work? Something like this:

```org
#+name: foo
|      3492-134.2 |
| 3492-134.2+1428 |


#+begin_src python :var tbl=foo :results output
  for row in tbl:
    print(eval(row[0]))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: 3357.8
: 4785.8
```

I think that's about the simplest you can do. You can add entries to the table, but the source block does not need to change.

Comment: +1 for simplicity and ability to use with different languages.